# how can i search a lots of .js and .php files for a specific phrase?

Tags: php, search, ide, javascript

Windows has a go at it but only gets a few when i seach a directory.

Is there an IDE or similar that allows for searching within the files of an entire directory?

> for example, if I need to make sure no files require to a redundant
>   class (old_class.php)
>   I'd like to
>   search for 'old_class.php'

or alternatively if anyone knows a way to do this in Aptana (my text editor of choice) that would be amazing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is easy with Aptana : 
[Doc: How to search with Aptana](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Searching_Aptana)

Comment: that's great! regex too! I'd never seen this menu becuase I always used ctrl-f to find things, i let you know if it's good! thanks again

Comment: You can use "Ctrl-J" if I good remember for incremental search too. (and Ctrl-Shift-J for reverse)

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ can search through multiple files.

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Edit: Oh and it's free!

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Windows GREP](http://www.wingrep.com/features.htm)**.
It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dreamweaver has amazing search capabilities for searching within folders. Very useful and used all the time. Obviously, it's not free. Would be happy to learn a way in Aptana

Answer (score 0):

Nothing better than [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (better than grep)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/)...